# How to define a link in laravel?

Tags: laravel, url

Hello I am new bee in `laravel`. I have an `<a>` tag. I want to give link in controller. I wrote

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('/controller'); }}">
```

But it prints same in addressbar:

> http://localhost:8000/{{ URL::to('/CategoryController'); }}

My `routes.php` file is OK.

**Should i need to change in any other file ?**

Comment: Does you file ends with the name `.blade.php` ?

Comment: yes my file ends with .blade.php

Comment: yes but plz any suggestion ??

Comment: What happens if you have this `{{ HTML::link('/controller') }}` ?

Comment: @David Please post the route definition and code that returns the Blade view file containing that link.

Comment: @Sulthan Allaudeen the [HTML and Forms](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html) packages are no longer part of the Laravel core, so unless the OP explicitly installed them, he would most likely get an exception.

Comment: @Bogdan Yes, But I would like to recommend installing HTML and Forms as it was an essential helper :) [ I faced many problems while using raw html tags in production server ]

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen I agree the HTML & Forms package is helpful, but it is by no means essential or even necessary. The OPs code looks fine without it, so the problem must lie somewhere else.

Comment: @Bogdan Yeah i agree with you too ! The Questioner seems to be freezed :p

Comment: Well, one problem is that he shouldn't have the semi colon. It should be: `<a href="{{ URL::to('/controller') }}">`